# mysql many to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql

hello I have two tables name **university** and **industry**. university will have many Industries and Industry will have many universities. So in order to implement this many to many relation I have created another table named as **university_industry**. It has ids of both university and industry as `uni_id` and `ind_id` . And I have a **student** table which has `uni_id` as the foreign id. So I want to get all those universities which is in student table but also with all the industries of those particular universities as well. This is the query I have done

```
SELECT university . * , industry . * 
FROM university
JOIN university_industry ON university_industry.uni_id = university.uni_id
JOIN industry ON industry.ind_id = university_industry.ind_id
WHERE university.uni_id IN (select uni_id from student where uni_id IS NOT NULL)
```

The problem with this query is I get the results like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [university] => Array
                (
                    [uni_id] => 1
                    [uni_name] => NYC Uni
                )

            [industry] => Array
                (
                    [ind_id] => 1
                    [ind_name] => Finance
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [university] => Array
                (
                    [uni_id] => 1
                    [uni_name] => NYC Uni
                )

            [industry] => Array
                (
                    [ind_id] => 2
                    [ind_name] => Accounting
                )

        )

)
```

I want the result something like this

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [University] => Array
                (
                    [uni_id] => 1
                    [uni_name] => NYU
                )

            [Industry] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ind_id] => 1
                            [ind_name] => Finance
                            [UniversityIndustry] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [uni_id] => 1
                                    [ind_id] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ind_id] => 2
                            [ind_name] => Accounting
                            [UniversityIndustry] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [uni_id] => 1
                                    [ind_id] => 2
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

So like I need all the industries in single index of array. So like it should be like this

1.NYC Uni

->accounting

->finance

instead of

1. NYC Uni

   ->accounting
2. NYC Uni

   ->finance

I hope you understand my problem. I am working on Php and I have no idea that wether I can achieve this certain result doing php code or I can achieve directly from the query.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve this from a single query as it always returns the data in tabular format. You must have to convert your data set in the code according to the format that you need